# Accessing call object representing a primitive type

Tags: java, class, primitive-types

I have read that in order to access the call object representing a primitive type,  I can do this:

```
Class intClass = int.class;
```

But how do primitive types have classes to represent them? They are primitive, which should mean they have no class. Why does the example above work, and what class contains `int` (Integer class maybe)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the javadoc for the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class states

> Instances of the class `Class` represent classes and interfaces in a
>   running Java application. An `enum` is a kind of class and an annotation
>   is a kind of interface. Every array also belongs to a class that is
>   reflected as a `Class` object that is shared by all arrays with the same
>   element type and number of dimensions. **The primitive Java types
>   (`boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double`), and the
>   keyword `void` are also represented as `Class` objects.**

A `Class` object simply provides some metadata and factory methods for the type it represents.

For example, [`Class#isPrimitive()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive--) will tell you if the represented type is a primitive.

The class `Class` and its instances are, among other things, used for reflection.

Let's say you had the a class like

```
public class Example {
    public long add(int first, long second) { // for whatever reason
        return first + second;
    }
}
```

and you wanted to invoke the `add` method, given only its name and parameter types. The following would fail

```
Class<?> exampleClass = Example.class;
exampleClass.getMethod("add", Integer.class, Long.class);
```

because the parameter types are not `Integer` and `Long`, they are `int` and `long`.

You'd have to do something like

```
Class<Example> exampleClass = Example.class;
Method addMethod = exampleClass.getMethod("add", int.class, long.class);
Example instance = exampleClass.newInstance();
addMethod.invoke(instance, 42, 58L);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the field summary for the `Integer` class, you will find that the primitive type `int` is actually represented by the class instance `TYPE`. Therefore, `int.class` would equal `Integer.TYPE`.

Here's a link to [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) where you can find the `TYPE` class instance.

Comment: can you give a link for a good tutorial on reflection that explain this concepts?

Comment: If you follow this trail on Oracle you will get a lot of useful information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 0):

When you type `int.class` you get the corresponding object wrapper class, which every primitive has. Read the [Java tutorials on autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for more information, and to see each primitive's corresponding wrapper class.